# How to convert strings in a text doc into list, and separate list into parts in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, text, format

I have the following words in a .txt file,

```
examplex
exampley
examplea
exampleb
exampleg
exampleh
```

I want to convert them into a list, then separate the list into sets of 2 in order to look like the output.

output:

```
 examplex, exampley
 examplea, exampleb
 exampleg, exampleh
```

Comment: So you need a list of tuples?

Comment: Please [share](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) the code you've tried and like feedback on.

Answer (score 0):

input.txt

```
examplex
exampley
examplea
exampleb
exampleg
exampleh
```

convert.py

```
r = open("input.txt", "r")
input = r.read()

output = ""
pair = 0

for i in input:
    # Every other '\n' character don't skip a line
    if(i == "\n" and pair % 2 == 0):
        output += ", "
        pair += 1
    # increment pair, but still add newline
    elif(i == "\n"):
        output += i 
        pair += 1
    else:
        output += i 

r.close()

# Write to output.txt
w = open("output.txt", "w")
w.write(output)
w.close()
```

output.txt

```
examplex, exampley
examplea, exampleb
exampleg, exampleh
```

Comment: Did this answer your question,  if so please accept.  Thanks!